# How do I find out which check digits algorithm was used to generate these check digits

Tags: decimal-expansion

199917310179
199957410250
199935910137
200025902253
199960710304
199836610072
199904610305
199911310180
199957710108
199957510123

The above are numbers which the ending number is a check digit for the entire number (apart from the last digit obviously)

I want to know which check digit algorithm is used to calculate this checksum 
I used  Luhn algorithm (1954), Verhoeff algorithm (1969) and the Damm algorithm (2004) with no luck, they create check digits but not the one already shown here

I am confident that these are valid number for the check digit, it's just that I don't know what the algorithm, can anyone help or give some pointers

Comment: Are they from barcodes ? If yes, can you show one ?

Comment: they are not from bar codes, they are from the national identity card of Sri Lanka, which has not published how they generate the check digit

Comment: At least try one of these, or variations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number. Sri Lanka might have taken inspiration there.

Comment: I posted the question after these test algo including the ISBN, IBAN among others including the raw modulo 10 and other variation, my question is there a way to reverse the formula or are there any good pattern identification formulas

Comment: Sorry.

Reversing the formula doesn't seem possible, as the checksum function performs a strong compression, from eleven digits to a single.

A pattern could be easier to spot if you could change a single digit at a time.

Comment: so what are the suggestions that you have on finding, any pointers or directions i can take on cracking this problem

Comment: Give us consecutive numbers.

Comment: I would not know how to give consecutive numbers
the format you see here is as follows
first four digits year
next three digits day from beginning of year | if you are female 500 gets added to the number
the remaining numbers are a birth certificate id, but the last is a check digits to prevent human errors etc, I need to know the formula inorder to ensure consistency

Comment: @MiyuruDharmage have you find the algorithm?

Comment: no i have not, and i gave up on it